Lefthook pre-push hook not working with Cypress
I currently have a pre-push hook with runs a suite of e2e tests from Cypress. When I manually type git push into my terminal lefthook will my cypress test suite. However, when I try using the Sync changes button in the source control panel of vs code, it just loads infinitely. At first I thought the load time was because it was also running cypress, but the loading goes on infinitely.
Additionally, when I run git push, my entire cypress test suite runs and passes successsfully. However, at it passes, instead of the push going through I'll get this message:
⠧ waiting: cypressConnection to github.com closed by remote host.
Then it'll go back to saying waiting for cypress, but this time it will just load indefinitely. Does anybody know why my testing doesn't terminate once everything passes?
Setup lefthook.yml file as follows:
pre-push:
  parallel: true
  commands:
    cypress:
      run: npm run cypress:run


Then ran the lefthook install command to add install the hooks which works. Lefthook will then correctly run on git push command, but won't exist after cypress after testing passess successfully. The problem isn't with the cypress commands since when I run cypress:run individually, it will run my tests then exit upon success/fail.
Additionally, the sync changes button in source control has the problems mentioned above.
